# How to send multiple values to a web server at once

Tags: php, android, mysql, database, hosting

My problem is, i keep track of users location per second, and it makes 60 values in an array in a minute. I wrote a simple php in my server to save the data to a mysql table. 
Because of the nature of the connection  (as far as i know) , i can save a record per one request with simple httppost object on android side.(request is like : xxx.com/writelocation.php?lat=33.76&lon=45.0&alt=12000)
I tried to solve this by using asynctask but it didnt work. Connection is slow and data is heavy.It takes more than a second for the connection to complete and at every second a new record comes.I am looking for a way to send multiple values at once, at every minute or so.So far, i couldn't find a solution other than using direct access to a remote database.
But my hosting does not provide remote access to my mysql database.

I need a clever and cheap solution for my problem :) what do you suggest?  is using remote database(by database hosting)only solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The request you are making is a http GET request. POST can send a lot more data to your server (the limit is up to server configuration). But creating a POST in android is different from GET.
You can try looking http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient

Comment: Why dont you try storing your data in an array() for the first minute ? You will have the time to send them asynchronously over the second minute and keep storing your new data.

Comment: I have solved the issue : I collect information in JSONObjects(lat, lon etc..), and then create an array of 60 seconds information in a JSONArray, send the JSONArray with HttpClient, on the php side, i get jsonarray with `code`$json = $_REQUEST['myjson']; and then decode with `code`$locationInfo = json_decode($json); and then iterate through the values and write them to mysql. it takes bout 3 seconds to complete with 3G+ connection. I will upload the code to [github](https://github.com/tekinbeyaz/FollowMe) once i figure out how to configure github with IntelliJ IDEA. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Json encoding is very fast and the bandwish consuming is really small. I suggest to yo to use json to send those data and then to parse the json on the server side and insert the data in the database.

To understand more abou json in android, see http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html

What do you think about ?

Comment: Yes, this is the solution. Thank you very much. I tried to explain the method in a comment to my question.

Answer (score 3):

**PHP**

With PHP it is possible to construct a multi-dimensional POST/GET array as follows:

(Assume this is part of the query string)
`id[]=1&id[]=2&id[]=3`

Produces:

```
array(1) {
   "ID" => array(3) {
       [1] => string(1) "1"
       [2] => string(1) "2"
       [3] => string(1) "3"
   }
}
```

Similarly, if you put text between the square brackets, you can utilize PHP's associative array functionality:

`form[fName]=John&form[lName]=Doe&form[age]=20`

Produces

```
array(1) {
   "form" => array(3) {
       ["fName"] => string(4) "John"
       ["lName"] => string(3) "Doe"
       ["age"]   => string(2) "20"
   }
}
```

Needless to say, this works with both POST and GET. You may be able to utilize it in your application, something like this:

loc1[lon]=longitude&loc1[lat]=latitude&loc2[lon]=longitude&loc2[lat]=latitude

So you get:

```
array(2) {
   "loc1" => array(2) {
       "longitude" => string(9) "longitude"
       "latitude"  => string(8) "latitude"
   }
   "loc2" => array(2) {
       "longitude" => string(9) "longitude"
       "latitude"  => string(3) "latitude"
   }
}
```

**MySQL**

Just a sidenote: Instead of running multiple insert queries, you may insert all the data at once and gain some speed advantages.
eg.

```
INSERT INTO `users` ( `fName`, `lName`, `age` ) VALUES ( "John", "Doe", "20" ),( "John", "Citizen", "42" )
```

In the above, we inserted two rows of data...

```
( "John", "Doe", "20" )
( "John", "Citizen", "20" )
```

Also, make sure your data is properly [escaped](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php). This may vary depending on the database API you use.

Answer (score 2):

use INSERT DELAYED instead of INSERT. also MySQL is not a really scalable solution for this case, maybe it's better to use MongoSQL fo this amount of requests. also you can save requests on the server as a text file and run queries as a batch every few seconds or minutes

Comment: Don't you think that PHP sessions would be a better solution than File I/O?

Comment: I have one-uped your comment for your suggestion of INSERT DELAYED, because I have never heard of it, and it seems like something that would be hard to use in the correct situation. Very good suggestion.

Comment: INSERT DELAYED is awesome :D specially when you're storing some logs in the db and you don't care that much about the exact order of the logs. MySQL handles it pretty well

Answer (score 2):

Trying to send each new location every second is a fundamental design flaw, and I would recommend avoiding this strategy, because you cannot guarantee network availability and latency from a mobile device.

The way to do it would be to buffer the data locally, and submit it over to the server in blocks. For example, collect ten minutes' worth of data and send that all in one go. Keep in mind that, aside from the network latency limitation that you'e already discovered, establishing and then tearing down connections has a network overhead and a battery life implication. Therefore it is better for many reasons that you buffer data locally and send the buffer after a sensible interval.

Each time you send the data to the server, do so within a POST request. This is the kind of request that should be used for submitting data of any significant size, and it also means that the data could be encrypted using TLS if that is a requirement for you later.

Comment: +1 for initiating request overhead, local buffer, POST request and future TLS-proofing. Very good suggestions here, I hope OP takes these into consideration in when developing his application.

Comment: Thank you very much for the warning. I was buffering the info in one minute arrays. I was looking for a way to send multiple rows of data at once because of this. If i haven't found a way to achieve this, i was thinking to send them one by one to remote database by direct connection. Hopefully I managed to solve it with help of this great community.